# Can't resolve 'Math/Long'./node_modules/bytebuffer/ByteBuffer.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'Math/Long'

Tags: reactjs

Hey all I'm trying to access the MTA's api in react using `import GtfsRealtimeBindings from 'mta-gtfs-realtime-bindings'`

yet i just keep getting this same error `Can't resolve 'Math/Long'./node_modules/bytebuffer/ByteBuffer.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'Math/Long'`

The more i read about it , seems like I might have an issue with webpack? I'm curious if anyone has ran into a similar issue before hand. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exact problem.

The way I "fix" this is go to ./node_modules/bytebuffer/ByteBuffer.js and change "Math/Long" to "long" under the AMD loading all the way in the button of the file.

Do the same if you have another similar problem where it can't find ByteBuffer in ProtoBuf.js-- change "ByteBuffer" to "bytebuffer".

This is not a permanent fix, as it will reset itself when npm update/install is executed.